# How to find a linear equation with the same solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have this homework question that I solved, but it was so easy that I feel like I did something wrong. Can someone just confirm that my approach to this problem was correct?

So, I have to find a linear equation that has the same solution set as the given equation. (possibly with some restrictions on the variables)

$$\frac{x^2 - y^2}{x-y} = 1$$

I simplified this to $x + y = 1$ by canceling $x-y$ from the top and bottom. Also, I said that $x-y$ cannot be equal to $0$ or $x$ cannot be equal to $y$. I got this from the original equation where $x-y$ is in the denominator.

Comment: This is indeed true, if you accept the system
$$\begin{cases}x+y=1\\x\ne y\end{cases}$$

Comment: You can't find a linear equation with the same set of solutions because the set of solutions of a linear equation forms an [afine space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) (think of it as a translated vector space) and the set of solutions to $\dfrac {x^2-y^2}{x-y}=1$ isn't an affine space.

Comment: @GitGud Note his remark "possibly with some restrictions on the variables".

Comment: @AlexR You're right. I'll keep my comment anyway as it isn't entirely useless.